# A built-in macOS way to copy annotated screenshots

Tags: screenshot, extension

WHen annotating a screenshot on Mac (13.3), I don't seem to be able to copy the "flattened" annotated version via Copy method (menu or right-click)

[image]

What is being placed on the clipboard is the original unannotated version.

Is there a built-in macOS way to achieve that?

and a related question:

Is it possible to create (using Automator) a sharing extension to appear in the menu, one that would do copy the annotated version?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can copy/paste it as soon as you've clicked 'Done'.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hitting Done closes the window and doesn't let me copy anything.

Comment: Tested as working on Mojave & Monterey, it hasn't changed over the years. How are you opening it in the first place? Spacebar? Ahhh… are you using the floating thumbnail?? That's truly useless;) Switch it off or wait the extra 5 seconds for it to disappear, & everything will behave properly.

Comment: Yes, you figured it right, I'm using Floating Thumbnail because this is my preferred workflow. I find more and more macOS builtins useless or inaccessible or not configurable, if not simply stupid.

Comment: The floating thumbnail is just weird. i switched it off day one. Anything you do to it is not saved until the file appears on the desktop.